# SOAP response containing SERIALIZED DICTIONARY is not valid in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, serialization, wsdl, xsd, soapui

My web service does not have any other attributes, beside dictionary, that I have serialized this way.

```
 public class DictionarySerializer : IXmlSerializable
    {
         private IDictionary dictionary;

    public DictionarySerializer()
    {
        this.dictionary = new Hashtable();
    }

    public DictionarySerializer(IDictionary dictionary)
    {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public void addToDict(object key, object value)
    {
        this.dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public static void Serialize(IDictionary dictionary, Stream stream)
    {
        DictionarySerializer ds = new DictionarySerializer(dictionary);
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionarySerializer));
        xs.Serialize(stream, ds);
    }

    public static IDictionary Deserialize(Stream stream)
    {
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DictionarySerializer));
        DictionarySerializer ds = (DictionarySerializer)xs.Deserialize(stream);
        return ds.dictionary;
    }

    XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.Read();
        reader.ReadStartElement("dictionary");
        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("item");
            string key = reader.ReadElementString("key");
            string value = reader.ReadElementString("value");
            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        foreach (object key in dictionary.Keys)
        {
            object value = dictionary[key];
            writer.WriteStartElement(key.ToString());
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString()); //WriteElementString("value", value.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }            
    }
    }
```

In my WS, I am dynamically filling my dictionary with attributes this way

```
            this.DICTIONARY.addToDict("WARRANTY", drv["Warranty"].ToString());
            this.DICTIONARY.addToDict("IMAGEURL", drv["ImageUrl"].ToString());
            this.DICTIONARY.addToDict("RETAILPRICE", drv["RetailPrice"].ToString());
```

and I am able to get response with SoapUI containing this dictionary elements:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetProductsResponse xmlns="http://www.xxx.com/B2B">
         <GetProductsResult>
            <PRODUCT>
               <DICTIONARY>
                  <IMAGE_URL>888009612_1.jpg</IMAGE_URL>
                  <WARRANTY>1G</WARRANTY>
                  <RETAILPRICE>0.00000000000000000000</RETAILPRICE>
               </DICTIONARY>
            </PRODUCT>
         </GetProductsResult>
      </GetProductsResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Problem is that response is NOT VALID against wsdl schema! Here is part of my wsdl that describes dictionary:

```
<s:element name="GetProductsResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetProductsResult" type="tns:ArrayOfPRODUCT" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfPRODUCT">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PRODUCT" nillable="true" type="tns:PRODUCT" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="PRODUCT">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DICTIONARY">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element ref="s:schema" />
                <s:any />
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
```

The error I get in SoapUI is this

```
Expected element 'schema@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' instead of 'WARRANTY@http://www.xxx.com/B2B' here in element DICTIONARY@http://www.xxx.com/B2B
Expected element 'schema@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' instead of 'RETAILPRICE@http://www.xxx.com/B2B' here in element DICTIONARY@http://www.xxx.com/B2B
Expected element 'schema@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' before the end of the content in element DICTIONARY@http://www.xxx.com/B2B
```

This is so much confusing me. I have no idea what is this error means and how to solve this issue, so that my response become valid against wsdl. Could you help me with this???

ps.

this is an old .asmx web service that needs some cosmetics. Am I going to solve this issue writing this service using wcf?

Thank for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone find this interested, I have solved this issue by myself. Because XMLSchema is expecting string, not List, I gave it a string in this way.

```
public string GetProducts(List<Product> lstProducts){
    string textReaderText = "";
    XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));
    TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StringWriter(new System.Text.StringBuilder(textReaderText));
    SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, lstProducts);
    WriteFileStream.Close();
    string stringresult = WriteFileStream.ToString();
    return stringresult;
}
```

this is SOLVED!

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is due to the dictionary serialization code: the de-serialization expects something like this:

```
<dictionary>
  <item>
    <key>the key</key>
    <value>the value</value>
  </item>
  ...
</dictionary>
```

but the serialization code generates:

```
<dictionary>
  <the key>the value</the key>
   . . . 
</dictionary>
```

The serialization should be something like this:

```
void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    foreach (object key in dictionary.Keys)
    {
        object value = dictionary[key];
        writer.WriteStartElement("item");
        writer.WriteElementString("key", key.ToString());
        writer.WriteElementString("value", value.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I tried this and now my soapresponse looks like this (snippet):

`<item>
    <key>WARRANTY</key>
    <value>1G</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key>RETAILPRICE</key>
    <value>0.00000000000000000000</value>
</item>`


but I am still getting error

**Expected element 'schema@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' instead of 'item@http://www.something.com/B2B' here in element DICTIONARY@http://www.something.com/B2B**